# Infite for-loop in an `init()` function of a package – good or bad idea?

Tags: go

I was wondering if it's a bad idea to have an **infinite for-loop** in an `init()` function of a package or if one should avoid doing that.

Does anyone have any knowledge or experience, if this can be done or should be avoided?

### Where would you use this?

This could be used for example for a package that provides some information from external sources that has to be refreshed periodically (like e.g. once per day).

I have used similar code as below, but without the "watchdog" function. Meaning the `init()` just started a go-routine that would run in the background and run the update process whenever a *tick* arrived.

Unfortunately, this update-mechanism stopped working after aprox. 3 months for unknown reasons, but the service was working fine, just with "old" data.

### Simple example implementation

Full example on https://play.golang.org/p/k-GI1t9J4oP

```golang
package info

import (
  "log"
  "sync"
  "time"
)

var (
  data map[string]interface{}
  lock sync.RWMutex
)

func init() {
  // ticker channel
  ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second).C

  // "watchdog" loop
  for {
    log.Println("Starting Update Loop")
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    // Start asyc update process.
    go func() {
      defer wg.Done() //notify wg when if process ends for whatever reason

      // Loop forever
      // Run when a tick is received from the `ticker` channel
      for {
        select {
        case <-ticker:
          log.Println("Update ticker received")
          err := update()
          if err != nil {
            log.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err.Error())
          }
        }
      }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
  }
}

// internal update function that retrieves some information from some external system
func update() error {
  lock.Lock()
  defer lock.Unlock()
  log.Println("Update `data`")
  // retrieve information and update `data`
  return nil
}

// Public function to query data
func GetInformation(key string) interface{} {
  lock.RLock()
  defer lock.RUnlock()
  return data[key]
}
```

The code works and runs fine for unit-tests and also running normally.
I was wondering about long-time stability (uptimes of 1 year and more) and the such.

Comment: "uptimes of 1 year and more" means you're not updating your kernel frequently enough. Don't do that. And you should expect failure anyway.

Comment: Generally, having an `init()` function is a bad idea...

Comment: @Flimzy can elaborate why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in a goroutine so it's technically fine but having behavior implemented directly in an `init` makes it very hard to work with for two reasons:

1. It's hard to test, in the same way that `main` is hard to test. It's much easier to test if `init` calls another function, which can then be tested.
2. It's hard to reason about. The more stuff that happens "automagically", the less sense it will make to any developer (including your future self) using that package. "OK I imported this package and used one tiny function and now somehow I went from 1% CPU use to 50% what did I do wrong" kind of things will come up and require a lot more spelunking to figure out than they should.

TL;DR there's no "long-term stability" problem but there's very likely a long-term maintainability problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fully agree on the maintainability part.
The code was mainly for illustration purposes :-)